# RC low pass filter not working as expected

Tags: high-voltage, low-pass, voltage-doubler

I have designed a high voltage power supply and I'm trying to filter out the switching noise.

I'm using a transformer that is driving a basic Cockroft-Walton voltage multiplier to a 1200V DC signal.

At the end of the voltage multiplier I have a 2nd order low pass RC filter on that doesn't appear attenuating the switching noise from my power supply.

My switching frequency going to the transformer is ~36kHz and the oscillation of noise I'm seeing on the output of voltage multiplier is ~350-400kHz.

Below is an oscilloscope image of before and after the RC filter.

[image: noise before and after RC filter]
[image: schematic of 2nd order RC filter]

According to the calculations (http://sim.okawa-denshi.jp/en/CRCRtool.php) I should be seeing a -150 to -180 attenuation of the noise, but in the real world I'm only seeing -10dB.

Any thoughts on why this filter is not working correctly?

Comment: Which trace is from where in the schematic ?

Comment: And can you post the layout of the filter ?

Comment: @tobalt Channel 2 is a resistor divider (5Gohm/1M) I added at HV-EXT to measure the high voltage. Channel 4 is "HV2-A2D" on the schematic.

https://imgur.com/oSj5cIK

Comment: Have you run the whole circuit in LTSpice? You seem to have a resonance you were not counting on.

Comment: Hmm looks alright, but if you have some large stray inductance in the filter caps, and some appreciable parallel capacitance across the resistors, the filter can become ineffective.

Comment: @MicroservicesOnDDD I have run the simulation on LTSpice and the noise and waveforms are similar before the low pass filter. In LTSpice the low pass filter works perfectly.

Comment: Can you give us a pic of your layout?

Comment: @MicroservicesOnDDD Layout is here: https://imgur.com/oSj5cIK

Comment: You have a lot of capacitance hard up against  the inductance of your transformer, under high pressure, so what is the natural resonant frequency of that? You may want to go from transformer to bridge to large capacitor, and drive the voltage multiplier separately, at a different frequency, or an opposite frequency to see how much ripple from stage 1 you can cancel in stage 2. If none of this makes sense, we need a clearer picture of what you've got. If you've got an echo chamber, might need to break it up.

Answer (score 2):

You're not showing the stray capacitance in parallel with R310, R318 and R319.

In a voltage divider, the C is often proportional to the R so no harm done, but in the filter, at 36 kHz, it could easily dominate the 1 M resistor. Each 4 pF of stray capacitance there has an impedance of about 1 Mohm, so if the nodes HV2A and HV2B are fairly bulky this could potentially be a problem.

The solution would be to reduce the capacitance, or to reduce all the filter component values to reduce the impact of the stray capacitance.

No simple PCB-mounted filter can achieve -120 dB though, for that you will need to separate the filter elements into their own milled aluminium housings. The PCB ground plane resistance and the inductive coupling between C322, C326 and C327 if they're nearby, will limit you to -60 dB or so.

Comment: Is there a method to measure the stray capacitance? Per you suggestion, would lowering the values of R318 and R319 solve the problem?

Comment: Do you have any suggested values for R318, R319, C326, C327 that might work better?

Comment: Well if the total capacitance isn't a problem for you (increased charge-up time) then try increasing C326,7 by 5 times? Also space them out more on the board to reduce parasitic capacitance, use several resistors in series, and add grounded guard traces which increase C to ground but decrease C across the R.

Comment: Also - you must respect the maximum V rating of the resistors, even if you're not exceeding the power rating. Resistors deviate from their value when V gets too high. Use several in series.

Comment: I didn't think I needed high voltage resistors because the voltage differential across the resistor is minimal (<5V). Is this incorrect thinking?

Comment: Yes I think you're right. (Except R306-7).

Comment: I tried using 0.1uF capacitors on C326/C327 but I didn't see any noticeable difference. I did order some high voltage MELF resistors to replace the thick film resistors I'm using at R310, R318, R319. Other than that I'm out of ideas unless you have another idea.

Comment: Maybe the filter is fine and it's simply coupling across the ground or somehow directly into your scope probe. Try removing R318, keep C327 and confirm you see no high frequency noise. How are you probing TP308, perhaps your ground is too long for these frequencies. Solder a piece of coax to the board instead, next to C327?